# Confusing use of a comma in an 'if' statement

Tags: c#, c++, if-statement

I have this piece of code in C++:

```
ihi = y[0]>y[1] ? (inhi=1,0) : (inhi=0,1);
```

But how would it look in C#?

Comment: excuse me yes cs = c#
and ihi and inhi are both interger types

Comment: @Byers IMHO http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)

Comment: this is someone trying to demonstrate how much they know I would change to one of the examples below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It means this:

```
if (y[0]>y[1])
{
    inhi = 1;
    ihi = 0;
} else {
    inhi = 0;
    ihi = 1;
}
```

Or written another way (in C++):

```
inhi = (y[0]>y[1]);
ini = !inhi;
```

Comment: yah, I was thinking same as your second version if they were basically bools.

Answer (score 9):

The comma operator binds lower than assignment, so the expression

```
inhi=1,0
```

sets `inhi` to `1`, and then returns `0`. Likewise

```
inhi=0,1
```

sets `inhi` to `0` and returns `1`. This whole thing is equivalent to

```
if(y[0] > y[1]) {
   inhi = 1;
   ihi = 0;
} else {
   inhi = 0;
   ihi = 1;
}
```

I'd suggest rewriting it this way, if you can. `inhi` and `ihi` seem to have the same purpose (in this statement), and the combination ternary operator (`?:`) and comma operator that you've got give them different weight.

Comment: this is clear, thanks for the explanation Jesse, the reason I was after a translation (from c++ to c#) was that like you said the (?:) and use of comma did not compile in c#.

Answer (score 1):

The [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) evaluates the arguments in turn and then returns the last evaluated expression. I.e. if you had the following code

```
int four = 2 + 2, mul(2,2), 4;
```

a strictly-following-the-specification non-optimizing compiler would first add 2 and 2 and then discard the result, then call the function `mul` and discard the return value and finally evaluate 4 which then is assigned to the `i` variable.

Notice that after each comma there is a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), so
all side effects of the previous evaluations will have been performed. E.g. in

```
ihi = y[0]>y[1] ? (inhi=1,0) : (inhi=0,1);
```

the assignment to `inhi` is done and finished *before* `ihi` is updated. And it also means that a compiler can not optimize away the call to `mul` in the example above unless it knows 100% for sure that the `mul` function does not have any side effects other than returning a value. That is normally not something the compiler knows, although in C++ it is possible to mark functions as `const` by which the compiler is told so.

Comment: -1, the first line will not compile and `const` doesn't work the way you describe in the last paragraph.